# If you flip three fair coins, what is the probability that you'll get two tails and one head in any order?

Tags: probability, combinations

I can't find a solution that doesn't involve listing out all the possible combinations. Is there a way that I can use combinations/permutations to easily calculate this by hand?

For example, when I'm solving "If you flip three fair coins, what is the probability that you'll get exactly two tails?" I can use combinations to find how many ways of getting exactly $2$ tails: $(\frac{3!}{2!\times1!})$. Then I can divide the answer by $8$, which is the total number of possible combinations $(2^3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just $$\binom{3}{2}*\dfrac{1}{2^3}=\dfrac{3}{8}$$

Think of it this way.

You have 3 slots.

$\text{_ _ _}$

I want two of them to be tail out of 3 (hence the $\binom{3}{2}$), and the probability of $2$ tails and $1$ head is basically $\dfrac{1}{2^3}$, as there are $1/2$ probability of head/tail for each toss, and there are 3 tosses.

---

Similarly I can choose 1 head out of 3, so that would make it $\binom{3}{1}$, and nothing else would change.

Answer (score 0):

When you flip $3$ coins, you either get a head or a tail. So getting 2 tails and 1 heads is  exactly the same event as getting exactly two tails. Thus, as you noted in the last part of your question, the answer is $\frac{3}{8}$.

Comment: Ok, no need to be rude. So the "in any order" portion makes absolutely no difference, correct?

Comment: @caroline In any order simply means that you can get the one head in the first, second or third toss which is what you counted in the second part of your question. Did not mean to be rude. Sorry. :P

Comment: Ok thanks! That makes a lot of sense. (And no worries, it's hard to tell tone over the internet)